# Typescript createProgram function seems to ignore the options variable

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a js program that calls the typescript compiler to get typescript warnings.
here is my test typescript file:

```
interface Message{
  a:string
  b:number
}
var a:Message={a:'hello'}
console.log(Object.values(a))
```

here is the js program that calls typescript compiler

```
const ts = require('typescript')

function compile (fileNames, options) {
  const program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, options)
  const emitResult = program.emit()

  const allDiagnostics = ts
    .getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)
    .concat(emitResult.diagnostics)

  allDiagnostics.forEach(diagnostic => {
    if (diagnostic.file) {
      const { line, character } = ts.getLineAndCharacterOfPosition(diagnostic.file, diagnostic.start)
      const message = ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(diagnostic.messageText, '\n')
      console.log(`${diagnostic.file.fileName} (${line + 1},${character + 1}): ${message}`)
    } else {
      console.log(ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(diagnostic.messageText, '\n'))
    }
  })

  const exitCode = emitResult.emitSkipped ? 1 : 0
  console.log(`Process exiting with code '${exitCode}'.`)
  process.exit(exitCode)
}

const options = {
  compilerOptions: {
    module: 'ES2015',
    target: 'ES2017',
    lib : ['es2017'],
    inlineSourceMap: true
  },
  reportDiagnostics: true
}

compile(['temp.ts'], options)
```

Here is the output:

```
temp.ts (5,5): Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type 'Message'.
temp.ts (6,20): Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2017' or later.
Process exiting with code '0'.
```

Regarding the second error, the error recommends setting the lib compiler option to 'es20017'. the problem is that lib compiler options is already set to 2017, it looks like the compiler just ignores it.

My question is: how do make the compiler not ignore the 'lib' option?

Comment: I see `lil`, but assume it should be `lib`.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev sorry, I copied the code here incorrectly - I just fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix compile time errors even using compiler options as target es6 and es2017 in Angular 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936918/how-can-i-fix-compile-time-errors-even-using-compiler-options-as-target-es6-and)

Comment: @eten, I tried the recommended fix, which is to increase the lib to es2018.  it had no effect

Comment: @yigal Try `npm install -D @types/node`. I replicated your problem, and it solved it for me.

Comment: @eten it did solve my problem, but why? why does the tsc works just fine without it? also: what other npm install do i needs? i have these errors Type 'Generator<{ func: Func; result: (value: any) => void; }, void, unknown>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIterati